# jquery ui autocomplete can not pass whole word to server in IE browser

Tags: jqgrid, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm use :

- jqGrid  4.4.3
- jQuery  v1.8.2
- jQuery UI  v1.8.24

I use jquery UI Autocomplete,when I put "P" in multiple search textbox,then autocomplete can show "P01","P02",

[image]

I select "P02" or other,in firefox that is ok,But in IE8 I get the filters is:

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"PNumber","op":"eq","data":""}]}
```

data is nothing!

In firefox is:

```
filters {"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"PNumber","op":"eq","data":"P02 "}]}
```

Why this different between IE and Firefox ?

My jqGrid colModel is:

```
 colModel: [
            {
                name: 'PNumber', width: 30, index: 'PNumber',
                searchoptions: {dataInit:pnumberAuto, sopt: ['eq', 'cn'] }
            }
           ]
```

My autocomplete code is:

```
 function pnumberAuto(e) {
    $(e).autocomplete({
        source: '/Autocomplete/QuickSearchPN',
        delay: 0,
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            $(e).val(ui.item.label);
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(e).val(ui.item.label);
        }
    })
}
```

And controller is(I use ASP.NET MVC 4):

```
public ActionResult QuickSearchPN(string term)
    {
        var q = (from p in db.BOM
                 where p.PNumber.Contains(term)
                 select p.PNumber).Distinct().Take(10);
        return Json(q, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I'm sorry, I left my coding crystal ball at home today. Can you provide us with a little more code?

Comment: For a long time,I find a way:

    function pnumberAuto(e) {
    $(e).autocomplete({
        source: '/Autocomplete/QuickSearchPN',
        delay:0,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            this.value = ui.item.value;
            **$(this).trigger('change');**
            return false;
        }
    })
}

The key is :

$(this).trigger('change');

Maybe is a bug in jquery ui autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function pnumberAuto(e) { 
    $(e).autocomplete({ 
        source: '/Autocomplete/QuickSearchPN', 
        delay:0, 
        select: function (event, ui) { 
            this.value = ui.item.value; 
            $(this).trigger('change'); 
            return false; 
        } 
    }) 
}
```